# in R Shiny, update an object based on user input

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I would like to have a plot of my graph (`g`) showing in my app at all times. I would like to have a 'default' value of `g` hard-coded into the app, and the user can update `g` via the UI.  I am using the {{igraph}} library and its functions, such as `make_empty_graph` and `add_vertices`.

I believe my main issue at this point is that I hard-code `g`, but then the reactive version of `g` is really `g()`.  I'm sure this problem has been solved many times before, but I can't see an example in the Shiny demos that does it.

Here's what I have inside `server()`:

```
g <- make_empty_graph(directed = TRUE) %>%
    add_vertices(nv = 1, depth = 0L, x = 0, y = 0, cur = TRUE)

g <- eventReactive(
    eventExpr = 'investigate',
    valueExpr = {
        add_children(g = g, vidx = input$vidx)
    }
)

output$the_plot <- renderPlot(
    expr = {    
       plot_graph(g())
    }
)
```

`add_children()` and `plot_graph()` are defined in the global namespace.  I am happy to share more code (or the whole app) if that is helpful.

Based on input from SO, the working version is:

```
g <- reactiveVal(
    make_empty_graph(directed = TRUE) %>%
        add_vertices(nv = 1, depth = 0L, x = 0, y = 0, cur = TRUE)
)    

observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$investigate,
    handlerExpr = g(add_children(g = g(), vidx = input$vidx)),
    ignoreInit = TRUE
)

output$the_plot <- renderPlot(plot_graph(g()))
```

Comment: `g` is a graph.  `make_new_graph` is a function from {{igraph}}.  I will clarify this above.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, here's a way using `reactiveValues` and `observeEvent` with `ignoreInit = TRUE`. Below app will start off with initial value 5 in `output$test` but will later depend on `input$slider`. This way you are always referencing to a reactive value in the output.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 10, 10),
  verbatimTextOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  graph <- reactiveValues(g = 5)# initial value

  observeEvent(input$slider, {
    graph$g <- input$slider # new value
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

  output$test <- renderPrint({graph$g})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: setting up `graph` as a `reactiveVal` seems like a good start -- thank you.

Comment: Don't forget `ignoreInit = TRUE` otherwise initial value will be lost when app starts.